# Computing quotient cayley graphs in GAP

Tags: graph-theory, gap, automorphism-group, cayley-graphs

1) $X1$ is a cayley graph and a is an automorphism (an element of Aut($X1$)) of $X1$. I'm trying to compute the quotient graph $X1$/a in GAP. I tired to use the command "QuotientGraph(X1,[a]);" in GAP but it is giving an error.

Can someone please help me with this question.

The steps of my computation is as below.

```
gap> Read("C:/Users/buddhini/Desktop/Test1/UndirectedGeneratingSets.gap");
gap> LoadPackage("grape");
```

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    Loading  GRAPE 4.8 (GRaph Algorithms using PErmutation groups)
    by Leonard H. Soicher (http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~lsoicher/).
    Homepage: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~lsoicher/grape/
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
     true

```
gap> Z3:=Group((1,2,3));
Group([ (1,2,3) ])
gap> Z3gen:=GeneratorsOfGroup(Z3);
[ (1,2,3) ]
gap> h:=Group((1,2,3,4,5));
Group([ (1,2,3,4,5) ])
gap> g:=DirectProduct(h,h);
Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10) ])
gap> Auts:=AutomorphismGroup(g);;
gap> AutsOfOrd3:=Filtered(Elements(Auts),elt->Order(elt)=3);;
gap> ExHom:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(Z3,Auts,[Z3gen[1]],[AutsOfOrd3[1]]);
[ (1,2,3) ] -> [ [ (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10) ] -> [ (1,5,4,3,2)(6,10,9,8,7), 
(1,2,3,4,5) ] ]
gap> s:=SemidirectProduct(Z3,ExHom,g);
Group([ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22) 
(17,18,23), (1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22)
(3,8,13,18,23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10) 
(11,12,13,14,15)(16,17,18,19,20)
(21,22,23,24,25) ])

gap> S:=IrredUndirGenSetsUpToAut(s);
[ [ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22) 
(17,18,23), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,
    15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ],
  [ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22) 
(17,18,23), (1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,
      8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23) ] ]
gap> S1:=S[1];
[ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), 
(1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,
15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ]
gap> X1:=CayleyGraph(s,S1);;
gap> H:=AutomorphismGroup(X1);
<permutation group with 4 generators>
gap> AutOfOrd5:=Filtered(Elements(H),elt->Order(elt)=5);;
gap> a:=AutOfOrd5[1];
(1,4,7,10,13)(2,5,8,11,14)(3,6,9,12,15)(16,19,22,25,28)(17,20,23,26,29) 
 (18,21,24,27,30)(31,34,37,40,43)(32,35,38,41,
 44)(33,36,39,42,45)(46,49,52,55,58)(47,50,53,56,59)(48,51,54,57,60) 
 (61,64,67,70,73)(62,65,68,71,74)(63,66,69,72,75)
 gap> QuotientGraph(X1,a);
 Error, usage: QuotientGraph( <Graph>, <List> ) at /proc/cygdrive/C/gap- 
 4.9.2/pkg/grape/lib/grape.g:2169 called from
 <function "QuotientGraph">( <arguments> )
  called from read-eval loop at *stdin*:41
  you can 'quit;' to quit to outer loop, or
  you can 'return;' to continue
```

Even if I use QuotientGraph(X1,[a]); it still gives an error.

2)I was able to read the vertices of the Cayley graph by identifying them as elements of the semidirect product group by using the commands below. Let V[2] be the vertex of Cayley graph I need to identify,

```
gap> V[2];
(2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23)
gap> proj:=Projection(s);
[ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), 
(1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22)(3,8,13,18,
23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,15) 
(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ] ->
[ (1,2,3), (), () ]
gap> e1:=Embedding(s,1);
[ (1,2,3) ] -> [ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14) 
(12,24,22)(17,18,23) ]
gap> e2:=Embedding(s,2);
[ (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10) ] -> [ (1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22) 
(3,8,13,18,23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25),
 (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ]
gap> a:=Image(proj,V[2]);
(1,2,3)
gap> b:=PreImagesRepresentative(e2,Image(e1,Image(proj,V[2]))^-1*V[2]);
()
```

Therefore the vertex is ((1,2,3),()).

When we consider the automorphism of $X1$ the vertices are again the elements of $s$, right?

So then is it possible to identify the elements of the automorphism $a$ by converting them to a form as above? I tried using the same codes but its not working.

(I just checked by taking $V$:=
    (1,4,7,10,13)(2,5,8,11,14)(3,6,9,12,15)(16,19,22,25,28)(17,20,23,26,29) 
     (18,21,24,27,30)(31,34,37,40,43)(32,35,38,41,
     44)(33,36,39,42,45)(46,49,52,55,58)(47,50,53,56,59)(48,51,54,57,60) 
     (61,64,67,70,73)(62,65,68,71,74)(63,66,69,72,75) , the representative of $a$, by thinking that this will be one of the elements of the automorphism but I don't know hoe to compute the remaining elements of the automorphism. Will it be by taking $V*V$, $V*V*V$,... etc. )

Please help and guide me with these questions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can't be sure without looking at your code, but I'm afraid that the type of the 2nd argument of `QuotientGraph` is not the one explained in https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/grape/htm/CHAP006.htm#SSEC009.1

Comment: Could you please add GAP input necessary to reconstruct the error?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov thanks a lot. I have added the GAP input by editing the question. Can you please help.

Comment: I also added another question faced during my computations to the edited question. Thank you very much in advance. I'm very grateful for the guidance.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov can you please help